# Get stored Data from CoreData using unique ID and date in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So, I'm working with an app that uses coreData in some of its features. Now, I have a problem with fetching the data from CoreData using a uniqueId and the current date. Also, I will also be getting the data weekly, monthly, and yearly with their corresponding unique id's. Can anyone help me in this? thanks

Comment: Why are you using date if you have uniqueId?

Comment: so for example I will fetch the data for a week, It can get the data that are stored in the db by date. It will check and fetch the data stored for the whole week.

Answer (score 0):

You should create 2 requests. One request to fetch datas by date, and other request to fetch data by uid.
To create a request, you should use [NSFetchRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchRequest/predicate) (There you can read how to create NSFetchRequest instances and how execute them).

I prefer to create access methods in categories of my models:

```
@interface CDModel (Access)
   +(NSArray)getModelsFromDate:(NSDate*)fromDate toDate:(NSDate*)toDate;
@end
```